# How to fetch data using functional components with hooks in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with nextjs and i am trying to use "functional component" with "hooks" for fetch
data using "axios",but i am getting following error `"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404"`
Here is my code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Post = () => {
  let params = useParams();
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(post => {
        setPost(post)
      });
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      {post !== null ? (
        <div>
          <h4>{res.data.title}</h4>
          <p>{res.data.body}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading post...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Post
```

Comment: The fetch is working fine for me, but you don't want to set `post` to the full response, but just to `post.data` Also, `res` doesn't exist anywhere in your componont so it won't work in your jsx, instead you'll need to `map()` over the posts returned. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-meadow-wgh11c?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Part where you are making request looks fine, but one that seems wrong is render part where you are trying to display `res.data.title` and `res.data.body`, but the problem is that `title` and `body` do not exist on response from `/posts` endpoint - this endpoint will return you array of random posts, meaning that `res.data` is an array which you can use in order to traverse and display posts.

Also I suggest you to rewrite `.then` part to:

```
.then(response=> {
    setPosts(response.data)
  })
```

As you can see I named input parameter as `response`, and not `post`(as you did), because this input parameter represents axios response which is wrapper around the data retrieved from endpoint. You should just store `response.data` inside inner state, no need to hold axios-specific. Also you should rewrite `[post, setPost]` to `[posts, setPosts]`, to plural, because this endpoint returns list of posts, and not just one single post.

**UPDATED**

Rewrite to something like this:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
 import axios from "axios";     

 const Post = () => {
  let params = useParams();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data)
      });
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      {posts !== null ? 
        posts.map(post => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h4>{post.title}</h4>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </div>
        ))
       : (
        <div>Loading posts...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Post
```

Comment: can you update my code so i can check and implement in my side

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: okay sure, i am waiting

Comment: `sePosts` is a typo. You might also mention that the data is a an array of objects and the OP should be using `map` to iterate over them using `post.title` etc to get at each object property.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic: i am getting error, "ReferenceError: useParams is not defined"

Comment: You should either import `useParams`, if you intend to use it for something, or just remove whole line if you do not need that hook.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic now i am getting following error " Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML "

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. It is something related with nextjs and your server/client side configurations. Try to find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Text+content+did+not+match+server

Comment: @MilosPavlovic still i am getting following error "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML "